# How to add overline on top of $\bm B$?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, bold

I represent a matrix in bold form throughout my paper, as `$\bm B$`. I need to add an overline to indicate a subtle transformation to this matrix. However the command `$\overline{\bm{B}}$` does not seem to work. Dito with using `$\bar$`.

How to achieve a line on top of a bold matrix?

Comment: Maybe embrace it: `$\bar{\bm  B}$` or `$\overline{\bm  B}$`

Comment: `\bar` is too short, `\overline` too long, in my point of view

Comment: Please show us a full working example that generates the problem behavior. For what it's worth, `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{bm} \begin{document} $\overline{\bm{B}}$ \end{document}` would appear to generate a line above a bold `B` without any problems.

Comment: @Mico: Does not work for me. I shall attach the example soon.

Comment: Both `\bar{\bm{B}}` and `\bm{\bar{B}}` work; also with `\overline` in place of `\bar`.

Comment: @Bravo - An expression such as "Does not work for me" is not at all helpful. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After showing how `\bar` and `\overline` can be made to work by embracing the argument,  I then introduce `\overlinebold` that scales with math style and perhaps looks better.  It uses the width of the upright version of the letter, and offsets the overstoke by 3mu to account for the italics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\overlinebold#1{\ThisStyle{\ooalign{%
  $\SavedStyle\mkern3mu\overline{\phantom{\mathrm{#1}}}$\cr $\SavedStyle\bm #1$}}}
\begin{document}
$\overline{\bm B}\quad \bar{\bm  B} \quad\overlinebold{B}$

$\scriptstyle \overline{\bm J}\quad \bar{\bm  J} \quad\overlinebold{J}$

$\scriptscriptstyle \overline{\bm M}\quad \bar{\bm  M} \quad\overlinebold{M}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use some markup command, say `\mymatrix` and the `\closure` command (by E. Gregorio (*egreg*), see the `comprehensive symbol table`) to provide a rule over the symbol which isn't to small or too wide.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\closure}[2][3]{%
{}\mkern#1mu\overline{\mkern-#1mu#2}}

\newcommand{\mymatrix}[2][3]{%
  \closure[#1]{\bm{#2}}%
}


\begin{document}
$\mymatrix{B}$
\end{document}
```